# Tidying a messy dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to put the following dataset in tidy format using pandas. I believe my variables are Group, Temperature, Flow, Pressure and Year but I am having trouble using pandas methods to restructure it properly.

```
  Group     Property   2012  2013  2014  2015  2016
0     A     Pressure   6057  1645   953  6333  5396
1     A  Temperature   5796  1494  1374  2013  3244
2     A         Flow   1425  1226  1903  1109  2805
3     B     Pressure  10522  1209  1312  2253  1232
4     B  Temperature   4712  1172  1877  2788  1163
5     B         Flow   1991  5366  1017  1582  5884
```

Comment: I don't think it's that messy. Just using melt should suffice: `df.melt(id_vars=['Group', 'Property'], value_vars=['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'], var_name='Year')` You might need to use integers 2012, 2013.. for the column names, I cannot see the types here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding of tidy data, you want variables in the columns.  I'd interpret `Group` and `Year` as observations and `Property` as variables.

```
df.set_index(
    ['Group', 'Property']
).rename_axis('Year', 1).stack().unstack('Property')

Property    Flow  Pressure  Temperature
Group Year                             
A     2012  1425      6057         5796
      2013  1226      1645         1494
      2014  1903       953         1374
      2015  1109      6333         2013
      2016  2805      5396         3244
B     2012  1991     10522         4712
      2013  5366      1209         1172
      2014  1017      1312         1877
      2015  1582      2253         2788
      2016  5884      1232         1163
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three solutions to this tidying this dataset:

Let's use: `set_index`,`stack`, `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['Group', 'Property']).rename_axis('Year',1).stack().unstack('Property').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
Property Group  Year  Flow  Pressure  Temperature
0            A  2012  1425      6057         5796
1            A  2013  1226      1645         1494
2            A  2014  1903       953         1374
3            A  2015  1109      6333         2013
4            A  2016  2805      5396         3244
5            B  2012  1991     10522         4712
6            B  2013  5366      1209         1172
7            B  2014  1017      1312         1877
8            B  2015  1582      2253         2788
9            B  2016  5884      1232         1163
```

Second, let's use: `pivot`, `stack`

```
df.pivot(index='Group',columns='Property').stack(0).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'Year'})
```

Output:

```
Property Group  Year  Flow  Pressure  Temperature
0            A  2012  1425      6057         5796
1            A  2013  1226      1645         1494
2            A  2014  1903       953         1374
3            A  2015  1109      6333         2013
4            A  2016  2805      5396         3244
5            B  2012  1991     10522         4712
6            B  2013  5366      1209         1172
7            B  2014  1017      1312         1877
8            B  2015  1582      2253         2788
9            B  2016  5884      1232         1163
```

Third, let's use: `pd.melt`, `set_index`, `unstack`

```
pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Group','Property'],var_name='Year').set_index(['Group','Year','Property'])['value'].unstack('Property').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
Property Group  Year  Flow  Pressure  Temperature 
0            A  2012  1425      6057         5796
1            A  2013  1226      1645         1494
2            A  2014  1903       953         1374
3            A  2015  1109      6333         2013
4            A  2016  2805      5396         3244
5            B  2012  1991     10522         4712
6            B  2013  5366      1209         1172
7            B  2014  1017      1312         1877
8            B  2015  1582      2253         2788
9            B  2016  5884      1232         1163
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott Boston! I think that `melt` is now a method in .20